# UFW Blocking Ethernet Connectivity?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I've isolated a connectivity issue to UFW. When I enable UFW, the connection to the web drops and I can't access the internet over it. `ping 8.8.8.8` starts returning operation not permitted.

How would I modify the rules to enable typical web traffic?

Here is my ip config:

```
sarah@LesserArk:/media/Wandering_Echo/Snapshots$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.133/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 85910sec preferred_lft 85910sec
    inet6 fe80::fc1e:6d15:705e:daae/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:70:b8:f8:99:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.212/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp7s0
       valid_lft 85919sec preferred_lft 85919sec
    inet6 fe80::1d67:e220:8994:a44e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**EDIT 0:**
Current UFW Status (How I'm posting right now):

```
sarah@LesserArk:/media/Wandering_Echo/Snapshots$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**After Activation:**
    sarah@LesserArk:/media/Wandering_Echo/Snapshots$ sudo ufw status
    Status: active

```
    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    45834                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    1714:1764/udp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    1714:1764/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    80/tcp on eno1             ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    80 on eno1                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    45834 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    1714:1764/udp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    1714:1764/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    80/tcp (v6) on eno1        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    80 (v6) on eno1            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

    45834                      ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
    45834 (v6)                 ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Add the results of `sudo ufw status` to your question.

Comment: `Status: inactive`

Comment: Same command, *after* you enable it.

Comment: There's a lot more ports than just port 80, etc. you need enabled to allow outbound.  Port 53 tcp/udp for DNS, for starters.  What's your default policy for OUTGOING, deny/block?

Comment: You need to open up port 443; that's your https connection.

Comment: This is rather curious. Why is it allowed over Wi-Fi? Wi-Fi works just fine, but the moment I plug in the ethernet cord with UFW up it just locks up. Also, could you post the code for opening up those ports? I'll accept and upvote your answer if it works :)

Comment: I just logged in to my Debian VM and the only ufw rule I have is for ssh connections. Maybe you need to reset your firewall (with **sudo ufw reset**) and start over. Question: did you happen to run **sudo ufw default deny** at one point? Take a look at this site for more info on setting up ufw: https://www.tecmint.com/setup-ufw-firewall-on-ubuntu-and-debian/